# dataframe merge with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df.head()
Out[2]: 
   Unnamed: 0 Symbol        Date      Close
0        4061      A  2016-01-13  36.515889
1        4062      A  2016-01-14  36.351784
2        4063      A  2016-01-15  36.351784
3        4064      A  2016-01-19  36.590483
4        4065      A  2016-01-20  35.934062
```

and

```
dfw.head()
Out[3]: 
         Symbol       Weight
0  A              (0.000002)
1  AA              0.000112 
2  AAC            (0.000004)
3  AAL             0.000006 
4  AAMC            0.000002
```

ISSUE:
Not every symbol if df will have a weight in dfw.  If it does not I want to drop it from my new dataframe (all dates of it).  If the symbol is in dfw I want to merge the weight in with df so that each row has symbol, date, close and weight.  I have tried the following but get NaN values.  I also am not sure how to remove all symbols with no weights even if I was successful.

```
dfall = df.merge(dfw, on='Symbol', how='left')

dfall.head()
Out[14]: 
   Unnamed: 0 Symbol        Date      Close Weight
0        4061      A  2016-01-13  36.515889    NaN
1        4062      A  2016-01-14  36.351784    NaN
2        4063      A  2016-01-15  36.351784    NaN
3        4064      A  2016-01-19  36.590483    NaN
4        4065      A  2016-01-20  35.934062    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df_all = df[df.Symbol.isin(dfw.Symbol.unique())].merge(dfw, how='left', on='Symbol')
```

I am not sure why you are getting NaN values.  Perhaps you have spaces in you your symbols?  You can clean them via: `dfw['Symbol'] = dfw.Symbol.str.strip()`  You would need to do the same for `df`.

```
>>> df_all
Unnamed: 0 Symbol        Date      Close      Weight
   0  4061      A  2016-01-13  36.515889  (0.000002)
   1  4062      A  2016-01-14  36.351784  (0.000002)
   2  4063      A  2016-01-15  36.351784  (0.000002)
   3  4064      A  2016-01-19  36.590483  (0.000002)
   4  4065      A  2016-01-20  35.934062  (0.000002)
```

Comment: i needed to add str. in front of strip(), df['Symbol'] = dfw.Symbol.str.strip()
dfw['Symbol'] = dfw.Symbol.str.strip()

Comment: actually, close, but, this gives me one occurrence for each symbol, I need to have the weight added to the symbol for each date.